# Comparing consistency of membership across multiple categorical variables

Tags: multiple-membership

I'm interested in testing for membership similarity between multiple categorical variables.

For instance, let's say that two categorical variables have the following membership:

```
Group1 = 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3

Group2 = 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3
```

I want to test how consistently samples group together across these variable. The name of (1, 2, 3) is arbitrary and strictly qualitative. In this instance, it would be a perfect match because the 2 matches bidirectionally to 1.

Is there a statistical test that I can apply to test this? I had read that $\chi^2$ might be appropriate, but I'm still a little fuzzy on how to interpret it in my application, because I don't think it would account for the bidirectional relationship between 1 and 2 in the different groups.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Group 1 and Group 2 are two distinct groups... With different people? What do 1, 2, and 3 represent theoretically? Different classes? I was thinking the phi coefficient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient but that may not be what you are looking for...